# ¿Rellenar un nuevo array con las posiciones de otro cuyo string empiece por una letra determinada?

Tags: java, array

Os cuento, tengo el siguiente código:

```
public static String[] empiezaPor(char buscada, String[] array) {
        String res = "";
        byte contador = 0;
        

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = array[i].toLowerCase();
            if (array[i].charAt(0) == buscada) {
                contador++;
            }
            if (array[i].charAt(0) != buscada) {
                array[i] = "";

            }

        }
        
        String[]nuevoArray=new String[contador];
        

      
        if (contador == 0) {
            return null;
        }else{
            for (int i = 0; i <array.length; i++) {
                if(array[i].charAt(0)==buscada){
                    nuevoArray[i]=array[i];
                }
                
                
            }
            
            
            
            for (int i = 0; i <contador; i++) {
                res+=nuevoArray[i]+" ";
            }
            
            System.out.println(res);
        }
        return nuevoArray;
    }
```

La intención es que copie el contenido de un array a otro si se cumple la condición de que el String en su interior comience por una letra que le pasaré por parámetros. He probado varias cosas entre ellas hacerlo todo en el mismo bucle for pero nada parece funcionar, ¿tenéis alguna idea? Gracias por adelantado.

Salen varios errores:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:709)
    at casa.parte3navidad.Funciones.empiezaPor(Funciones.java:57)
    at casa.parte3navidad.Parte3.main(Parte3.java:32)
```

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: @wowin, podrías poner un ejemplo para entender mejor

Comment: Agrega los errores en la pregunta para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: He comprendido tu intención.. solo tengo la duda si quieres que el arrays que vas a copiar los elementos, quieres que dónde no aparece la letra al comienzo, quieres que no aparezca en el segundo arrays o que el valor sea otro valor por defecto?,  Ejemplo: que el valor sea nulo o una cadena vacía?

Comment: La idea es que copie los campos de un array "A" cuyo String empiece por una letra determinada, a un array "B". Las posiciones con vacío no se copian.

Answer (score 1):

2 situaciones a corregir:

1. En el primer **for**, cuando el string no empieza con el caracter buscado lo cambias a un string vacío (""), en el segundo for (que copia al nuevo array) el método charAt(0) genera un error, porque la cadena esta vacía.

Borrar

```
 if (array[i].charAt(0) != buscada) {
            array[i] = "";
        }
```

2. En el **For** que copia las palabras necesitas un segundo indice para el nuevo array, sino vas a introducir la palabra en posiciones que pueden no existir en el nuevo array. (ej nuevo array tiene espacio para 5 elementos (indices de 0 a 4) la palabra que empieza con el char buscado está en la posición (i) 7, en nuevo array no existe esa posición).

   ```
    int j = 0; // nuevo indice, puede ir dentro del for
    for (int i = 0; i <array.length & j < contador; i++) {

        if(array[i].charAt(0)==buscada){
            nuevoArray[j]=array[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
   ```

Saludos.

Comment: Buenos días y Feliz Año! El campo vacío no puede eliminarse puesto que se arrastra de un trabajo anterior en el que me tenía que devolver solo las posiciones del array que empezaran por la letra que pasara por consola y la idea es no modificar nada del anterior...si hubiera otro método para hacer ese campo nulo...pero probé varios y sólo ese parecía funcionar.

Comment: Hola @wowin siempre se puede encontrar otra forma, en este caso si no se puede eliminar esa parte del código, se puede agregar otra condición antes de evaluar el primer caracter por ejemplo: `if(!array[i].isEmpty() && array[i].charAt(0)==buscada)`

Comment: **isEmpty()** evalúa si la cadena es vacía, esta negada porque buscamos lo contrario. Con **&&** se evita que se ejecute la segunda condición si la primera fallo. Si esto no resuelve el problema avísame, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomendaría lo siguiente:

1. Cambiar el tipo de parametro de la función por:

   ```
    public static String[] empiezaPor(String buscada, String[] array)
   ```
2. Reemplazar los charAt(0) por startsWith:

   if(array[i].startsWith(buscada)

Ahora si no puedes modificar la declaración de la función entonces conviertela en el cuerpo:
String strBuscada = Character.toString(buscada);

y la utilizas en  todas las evaluaciones:

```
  if(array[i].startsWith(strBuscada)
```

No obstante lo anterior, la solución que te aconsejo es utilizar un ListArray para el nuevo array:

```
  public static String[] empiezaPor(char buscada, String[] array) {
    String strBuscada =  Character.toString(buscada);     
    List<String> listNuevo = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i].toLowerCase();
        if (array[i].startsWith(strBuscada){
            listNuevo.add(array[i]);
        }

    }
    String[] nuevoArray = listNuevo.toArray(new String[listNuevo.size()]);     
    return nuevoArray;
```

}

Espero te sea de utilidad. El codigo anterior le falta colocar algunas validaciones como preguntar si listNuevo tiene elementos antes de crear el nuevoArray.